# PBS Torque Limit Resource by Time of Day

Tags: torque, job-scheduler, pbs, job-control

I am using Torque to manage software that I have a limited number of licenses of (4 to be exact). During the day I need to keep 2 licenses free for use of setting up cases and at night and over the weekend I can use all 4 licenses to solve cases. Is there any way to set up Torque such that it holds 2 licenses back from say 6am until 6pm Mon through Fri but still uses all 4 at other times?